# Ionic storage not working in chrome browser

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am new to Ionic app development and I have been following tutorials for the same.

I have been trying to use `IonicStorageModule` but even though there are no errors while running the app in chrome browser mobile view mode, local storage keys are not being generated.

In my `app.module.ts`, I have

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
```

Then I have the following import in `imports` array,

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
```

Now, I created a service, named `user-settings.service.ts`,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class UserSettings {
    constructor(private storage:Storage){}

    favoriteTeam(team,tournamentId, tournamentName) {
        debugger;
        let item = { team: team,tournamentId : tournamentId, tournamentName : tournamentName};
        this.storage.set('teamId' , item);
    }

    unFavoriteTeam(team) {
        this.storage.remove(team.id);
    }

    isFavoriteTeam(team) {
        return this.storage.get(team.id).then(value => value ? true : false);
    }
}
```

And from my component, class, when I do..

```
}else {
  this.isFollowing = true;
  this.userSettings.favoriteTeam(this.team,this.currentTournamentData.tournament.id,this.currentTournamentData.tournament.name);
}
```

Even though service, is being hit, I cannot see `local stoarge` keys being created in chrome `application -> storage -> local storage.`

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Check if you are using mac and not the private browsing mode?

Comment: @DeepakJha Not it's not private browsing mode but I am using mac for sure.

Comment: Well I have run into same problem once, actually apple cloud doesnt allow to store anything coming from web, but I also remember then I was facing an error which reads as "max stack size reached" I may be incorrect in my error statement but it was something close to that. I would suggest you also search for this option if you are allowed to store anything from your system in applecloud.

Answer (score 10):

Just like you can see in **[the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/)**:

> When running in the web or as a Progressive Web App, Storage will
>   attempt to use **IndexedDB**, **WebSQL**, and **localstorage**, in that order.

So if you're using Chrome, check if the data is being stored in IndexedDB or in WebSQL first:

[image]

Also please notice that you're setting the data using the `teamId` key, like this:

```
this.storage.set('teamId' , item);
```

So in order to get that data back, you need to use the same key:

```
this.storage.get('teamId').then(value => value ? true : false);
```

And the same if you want to remove it from the storage:

```
this.storage.remove('teamId');
```

Comment: Dear downvoter could you please explain the reason for your vote? That way we can all learn :)

Comment: I think `StackOverflow` **must** give that feature. **i.e.** No one can downvote without mentioning the reason for it. Your thoughts?